# Bug: Wrong behavior involving console, active selectors and cursor

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woy30dz2/1/) for a bug demonstration.  I will also provide an explanation below for convenience.

This is an example snippet in which the bug can be reproduced (Chrome only).

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#testing{
  background-color:blue;
  cursor:-moz-grab;
  cursor:-webkit-grab;
  cursor:grab;
}

#testing:active{
  cursor:-moz-grabbing;
  cursor:-webkit-grabbing;
  cursor:grabbing;
}

#testing2{
  background-color:green;
}

#testing2:active{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='testing'></div>
<div id='testing2'></div>
```

## TO REPRODUCE:

**1) Run snippet.**  Hover over the BLUE box, then click and drag.  It should be working as intended (cursor should change to hand on hover, then to dragging hand on click and drag).

**2) Open the console.** (ctrl+shift+i)

**3) Switch to a new tab.**

**4) Switch back to this tab.**

**5) Now try dragging the BLUE box.**

It would appear (on my device, at least), that the behavior changes; it only changes to a dragging cursor after the mouse goes up, and as soon as the mouse is moved even the slightest bit, it goes back to the original hand cursor.

The bug goes away as soon as

**6) You close the console.**

Notice that clicking and dragging on the GREEN box (which will change to yellow when clicked) works as intended even after switching tabs with the console open.  This leads me to believe that the bug is cursor-related.

*Yes, I know this is a minor bug*; however, it caused me about a half hour of frustration because I keep my console open as I work.  It wasn't until I restarted chrome that it starting work right again, and I was able to trace it down to the console.

## BUG SUMMARY:

In Chrome, elements which change cursors on active will behave improperly when the console is open and the user switches tabs.

Can anyone reproduce this bug/explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce. But behavior is slightly defferent with and withour console. (In my console JS in *enabled*).

Comment: JS is enabled just fine.  Weird, maybe it's something else that's causing the bug on my end.

Comment: By the way, if you have only one computer, you could install Chrome Canary and test on it.

Comment: Installed and tested on Canary to the same effect...I'm really at a loss for what could be going on with this.  I could perhaps post a video showing the bug?

Comment: In any case, it would be better. But to be honest I don't understand why it bothers you so much. In real life, when user working with your site, console is closed.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this. Have you reported this on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?

Comment: jsv yeah, like I said really not a big deal, but it did confuse the hell out of me for about half an hour...figured it's a bug, whatever, I'll report it lol.  @j08691 Haven't yet, will do now, wasn't really sure about the typical procedure for effective bug reporting so figured I'd make a stack post.